# Radio button inside the UITableview not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I wish to add radio button to UITableview. The function of radio button should be like when I select radio button in the table cell that radio button should be selected and other all radio buttons in the other cell should be unselected. It should be kind of either or, that is only one radio button can select.

Comment: add some code regarding your radio button and cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the one `int` value

```
int selectstr;
 UIButton * button;


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];




if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

}



UILabel  * title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 14.0, 215.0, 36.0)];
title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
title.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
title.tag=indexPath.row;
title.text = @"TEST";
// title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Hebrew" size:16.0f];
 title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:14.0];
[cell.contentView addSubview:title];




button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 46.0f, 30.0f)];
button.tag=indexPath.row;

if (selectstr ==indexPath.row)
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(243.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(74.0/255.0) alpha:1.0f];

}
else
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

}
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleCheckedMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];






return cell;

}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

selectstr=indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadData];


 }


  - (IBAction)toggleCheckedMode:(UIButton*)sender
  {

   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // here customized for your self
    selectstr=sender.tag;
     [tableView reloadData];

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah it is working good in didselect. But i am looking for same function in radio button on click.

Comment: I modified the code for yourself , plz see the code, if u need assistance i hope with u

Comment: It is working great as we expected. Thanks karthik jpa

Comment: then up vote my answer bro, do u know me ,if yes karthik.saral@gmail.com (Gmail, Skype, FB, stack overflow),

Comment: you too bro, tanx and have a happy day

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can i have your Skype id

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have heared about you anna and i give you request in Skype

Comment: @karthikeyan do u know me ma,

Comment: yes...i have seen you in stack overflow last four months and shanthakumar told me about you..i given request accept

Comment: oh k ma, nice to meet u ma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60533/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

```
Write this code into 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;
    UIButton *radioButton;

radioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    radioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30,23,24,24);
    // [radioButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    radioButton.tag = 8888;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:radioButton];
    radioButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8888];
    if (selectedIndex && selectedIndex.row == indexPath.row)
    {
        [radioButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [radioButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndex =indexPath;
    [self.userTabelView reloadData];
}
```