# How to create a radio button in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am having a radio button in table view cell. This is my radio button

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

 radiobtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    radiobtn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);

    [radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [radiobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = radiobtn;
}
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;

}

-(void)radiobtn:(id)sender

{


 if([sender isSelected])

{
[sender setSelected:NO];
}  else
[sender setSelected:YES];
} }
```

In the above coding radio button is not changing to selected state. Please help me in coding.

Comment: try this link it is useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642756/radio-button-inside-the-uitableview-not-working/25642856#25642856

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the images for both selected and unselected state while creating the button.

```
radiobtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
radiobtn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);
[radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 radiobtn.tag=1;
[radiobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = radiobtn;
```

On button click, you just have to change the selected state.

```
-(void)radiobtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([sender isSelected])
    {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }

     else
     {
         [sender setSelected:YES];
      }
}
```

Comment: sender.selected = !sender.selected;

Comment: Thanks. I have changed id but i think the if else will be more explanatory for beginners.

Comment: bro its working thanks but this radio button occur in 10 rows of the table. only one button click at a time. what can i do for that..

Comment: @Ayan Khan i declare it in cellforRow only. i cant get it . please help me

Comment: @Ayan Khan removed but not working still i can select all the radio button in the table view..

Comment: You are still using global radiobtn...ihave edited my code replace your cellForrow with mine.....

Comment: @Ayan Khan I have changed  to local . still i can select all the buttons in the table view

Comment: Tell me what you exactly want either you want radio button only on perticular cell or all cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
UIButton *newRadioButton;
newRadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
newRadioButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 15, 14.5);

[newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newRadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[newRadioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = newRadioButton;
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}
```

Comment: I have edited....replace those with these two methods and let me know if working then ill explain whats the issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set target action for the control event UIControlEventValueChanged.
2. Set the image for certain state before the action happened (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method). By using the `setImage:forState:` you don't actually change the current control image, you just say the control use exact image for certain control state on that state occurred. Don't use `highlighted` state in case `selected` state is more appropriate. Try to change the state programmatically by `[radiobtn setSelected:YES]` or `[radiobtn setSelected:!radiobtn.isSelected]`.